# Read and play audio files from a directory with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, stream, node-modules

I'm working on a project to create an audio streamer (like an online radio) using NodeJs.
And in principle, I have this code in my app.js file, the main objective is to go through the files in a folder and play them one by one, but I have had problems to do it, I could only transmit a single file as shown in the code. What changes should I make to be able to go through the directory and 'broadcast' the audios one after another?

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const app = express();
const port = 8001;

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Port Number:', port);
    const folderPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public/playlists/gral/');
    const totalFiles = await getTotalFiles(folderPath);
    console.log(totalFiles);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/playlists/gral/La_Mirla.mp3'));
});

async function getTotalFiles(folderPath) {
    try {
        const files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
        const totalFiles = files.length;
        console.log(`Total files in ${folderPath}: ${totalFiles}`);
        return totalFiles; // Return the total number of files
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error reading folder:', err);
        return 0; // Return 0 in case of an error
    }
}

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to read multiple files in Node.js using ReadStreams and create a continuous stream from them. When one file ends, the next file should be read and appended to the stream.

For that I would recommend not to use the `res.sendFile` function but rather just use the normal `res.write` function and supply a stream to it.

In my Idea your sending process should look a little like this:

```js
const filesToRead = ['file1.mp3', 'file2.mp3', 'file3.mp3'];

const continuousStream = createContinuousStream(filesToRead);

continuousStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  // send each chunk
  res.write(chunk);
});

continuousStream.on('end', () => {
  // end the uplink
  res.send();
});

continuousStream.on('error', (err) => {
  // Handle errors in the stream
  console.error(`Stream error: ${err.message}`);
});
```

So the `createContinouseStream()` function is actually not that hard. You basically create a readStream and replace its `read()` function with your own where you keep track of the current file and switch to the next one.

```js
function createContinuousStream(files) {
  // keep track of the current file
  let currentIndex = 0;
  // create Readstream
  const readableStream = new Readable({
    // replace the standard read function with your own to handle the file switch
    read() {
      // check if there are files left
      if (currentIndex < files.length) {
        // actually read the file to a stream
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(files[currentIndex]);

        fileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
          // Push the data chunk (from the fileRead)) to the readable stream
          this.push(chunk)
        });

        fileStream.on('end', () => {
          // Move to the next file when the current file ends
          currentIndex++;
          // Resume reading (starts reading the next file)
          fileStream.resume();
        });
        
        fileStream.on('error', (err) => {
          // Handle errors, you might want to emit an error event or handle it in some way
          console.error(`Error reading file: ${files[currentIndex]}, ${err.message}`);
          // Move to the next file even if an error occurs
          currentIndex++;
          // Resume reading from the next file
          fileStream.resume();
        });
      } else {
        // End the stream when all files have been read
        this.push(null);
      }
    },
  });

  return readableStream;
}
```

Oh and don't forget to import the Readable Stream:

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream');
```

I am using a slightly different approach in one of my projects. I am Streaming a Video from a fetch endpoint and extract the audio from it to a seperate stream using ffmpeg. This audio then gets send to the client making the request also as a stream.